# No attribute for CSS class

Tags: html, css, asp.net, webforms

Google isn't offering much help, probably because I don't know how to phrase my question. Is there a way to specify the CSS class for a particular type of elements through `<style>`? For example, if I want all the checkboxes in my `div` to have a "checkbox-inline" `class` (yes, that's Bootstrap), can't I do something like:

```
<style>
     input[type=checkbox] 
     {
         class: checkbox-inline;
     }
</style>
```

This doesn't seem to work. There is no `"class"` attribute (at least not shown by Intellisense).

Comment: I am not sure about applying class using CSS, using Jquery it is definitely possible. But you can always write the properties of class checkbox-inline inside `input[type=checkbox] 
     {
         /* all css properties of class checkbox-inline can go here */
     }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this isn't what CSS is for.

You can do this with JavaScript though, but this will only happen after your page has loaded:

#### Pure JavaScript

```js
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');

for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++)
  elems[i].className += " checkbox-inline";
```

```css
.checkbox-inline {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" /> Checkbox 1<br>
<input type="checkbox" /> Checkbox 2<br>
<input type="checkbox" /> Checkbox 3<br>
<input type="checkbox" /> Checkbox 4
```

#### jQuery

```js
$('input[type=checkbox]').addClass("checkbox-inline");
```

```css
.checkbox-inline {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" /> Checkbox 1<br>
<input type="checkbox" /> Checkbox 2<br>
<input type="checkbox" /> Checkbox 3<br>
<input type="checkbox" /> Checkbox 4
```

The best solution, however, would be to alter your HTML files manually.

Comment: Fair enough. Although almost all the answers are saying the same thing, this one is better than others in quite a few ways. Accepting. Thanks.

Comment: And I can't alter HTML files. The output code is generated by ASP.NET `CheckBoxList` control.

Comment: @dotNET in that case the best option would be to alter your ASP.NET code to add the class in. IIRC ASP.NET controls have a `CssClass` property, but it's been a long time since I've used ASP.NET so this may be incorrect.

Comment: ASP.NET controls do have `CssClass` property, but `CheckBoxList` is a composite control that renders a `table` in the output, which in turn contains checkboxes that I'm targeting. So using `CssClass` doesn't help much. Anyway, I guess I can live with JS. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

CSS cannot be used for operations like that. You would need JavaScript to add classes to certain elements.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way using CSS to set a class of an item.

If you want to change the class of an element, you will have to do it with Javascript.

Since you are already using bootstrap, you can utilise jQuery too.
Something like this might work:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {
    $(this).class('checkbox-inline');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to add a class on all the checkboxes in a div. Sorry, this won't be possible without using JAVASCRIPT.

Or if you're using jQuery in your project, you will be able to do it in even less lines of code

Answer (score 0):

No you can's but if you are using Bootsrap why not using jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("input[type=checkbox]").addClass('checkbox-inline');
});
```